# Appending to a numpy array or list inside a for loop- which is preferable?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on some code which looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1,0,3,5,7],[4,0,6,2,3]])

def SMD(matrix):
if isinstance(matrix,np.ndarray)==False:
    raise ValueError('The needed datatype is an array')
else:
    m= matrix.shape[0]
    n= matrix.shape[1]
    a=np.array([])
    b=np.array([0])
    c=np.array([])
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if matrix[i][j] !=0:            
                np.append(a,matrix[i][j])
                np.append(c,j)
        np.append(b,len(a))
    return a,b,c
```

However, the numpy append does not work for me in this case. If I instead use lists instead of arrays, the code runs just fine:

```
def SMD(matrix):
if isinstance(matrix,np.ndarray)==False:
    raise ValueError('The needed datatype is an array')
else:
    m= matrix.shape[0]
    n= matrix.shape[1]
    d=[]
    e=[0]
    f=[]
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if matrix[i][j] !=0:  
                d.append(matrix[i][j])
                f.append(j)
        e.append(len(d))
    return d,e,f
```

the wanted output is:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 2, 3], [0, 4, 8], [0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or as arrays (depending on the code used).

Of course, I would like to know why the first code is not working.

From my knowledge, it can be preferable in terms of computation speed to use arrays, but in this case, does it make a difference?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to reread the np.append docs`  It isn't a list append clone.  It is also slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of efficiency you you should avoid loops

```
def SMD(matrix):
    bool_matrix = (matrix!=0)
    return (
        matrix[bool_matrix],
        np.append(0, bool_matrix.sum(1).cumsum()),
        np.where(bool_matrix)[1]
    )

SMD(A)
#(array([1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 2, 3]),
# array([0, 4, 8]),
# array([0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4]))
```

`matrix[bool_matrix]` are simply all the non-zero elements of `matrix`

`np.append(0, bool_matrix.sum(1).cumsum())` first compute the number of non-zero elements in the rows of `matrix`; then it compute the cumulative sum (from the first row to the last one); finally it add the `0` at the beginning of the array.

`np.where(bool_matrix)[1]` tells you the indices of the columns in which the elements of `matrix` are non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

`np.append` returns the appended array, it does not do in-place append. so you will have to save the returned values.

Fixed Code:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1,0,3,5,7],[4,0,6,2,3]])

def SMD(matrix):
  if isinstance(matrix,np.ndarray)==False:
      raise ValueError('The needed datatype is an array')
  else:
      m= matrix.shape[0]
      n= matrix.shape[1]
      a=np.array([])
      b=np.array([0])
      c=np.array([])
      for i in range(m):
          for j in range(n):
              if matrix[i][j] !=0:            
                  a = np.append(a,matrix[i][j])
                  c = np.append(c,j)
          b = np.append(b,len(a))
      return a,b,c
```

#### Optimised code

Since you are using numpy you can as well vectorize it and avoid loops:

```
a = A[A!=0]
b = np.pad(np.cumsum(np.sum(A!=0,axis=1)), (1,0))
c = np.argwhere(A!=0)[:, 1]

print (a,b,c)
```

Output:

```
[1 3 5 7 4 6 2 3] [0 4 8] [0 2 3 4 0 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Running times on the 2 versions (with the correction by `ags29`)

list:

```
In [91]: timeit SMD(A)
8.76 µs ± 67 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

array:

```
In [92]: timeit SMD1(A)
206 µs ± 198 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

`np.append` is a poorly name cover function for `np.concatenate`.  It is ok for adding one element to an array - provided you pay attention to the docs.  But like `concatenate` (and all the `stack` functions), it does not operate in-place.  It returns a new array, and that makes it much slower when done repeatedly (in a loop like this).

The array append output:

```
In [90]: SMD1(A)
Out[90]: 
(array([1., 3., 5., 7., 4., 6., 2., 3.]),
 array([0, 4, 8]),
 array([0., 2., 3., 4., 0., 2., 3., 4.]))
```

If you really needed array output, we usually recommend doing the list append, and end with one `np.array(alist)` wrapper.

The list version is still faster than the no-loop array alternatives:

Salvatore's:

```
In [98]: timeit SMD2(A)
34.1 µs ± 58.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

mujjiga's:

```
In [101]: timeit SMD3(A)
100 µs ± 51.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

If I rewrite your function to work with a nested list, I get even better times:

```
In [118]: def SMD5(matrix):
     ...:         m= len(matrix)
     ...:         n= len(matrix[0])
     ...:         d=[]
     ...:         e=[0]
     ...:         f=[]
     ...:         for i in range(m):
     ...:             for j in range(n):
     ...:                 if matrix[i][j] !=0:
     ...:                     d.append(matrix[i][j])
     ...:                     f.append(j)
     ...:             e.append(len(d))
     ...:         return d,e,f
In [120]: timeit SMD5(A.tolist())
3.94 µs ± 159 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

For a much larger array I expect Salvatore's version will scale much better.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason your code doesn't work is that you are not assigning the output of the `np.append` operations back to `a,b,c`. Below is a version of your code that works:

```
def SMD(matrix):
    if isinstance(matrix,np.ndarray)==False:
        raise ValueError('The needed datatype is an array')
    else:
        m= matrix.shape[0]
        n= matrix.shape[1]
        a=np.array([])
        b=np.array([0])
        c=np.array([])
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                if matrix[i,j] !=0:
                    a = np.append(a,matrix[i,j])
                    c = np.append(c,j)
            b = np.append(b,len(a))
        return a,b,c
```

In terms of efficiency, it would probably be better to initialise `a,b,c` upfront with the correct sizes (using e.g. `np.empty`) and then assign the values in the loop.